# VueJS: :class, condition with index

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a list of (thumbnail) 2 images, and @click each image should be expanded to max-width, by adding said class ('max-w-full') to the  classes. The class is added by setting the array entry with the same index nr. as the image (imgclicked[0], imgclicked[1]) in the list to 1.

```
data:() {
    imgclicked=[0,0], //by default both are set to 'small'/not 'max-w-full'
},
```

the template part looks like this:

```
<template v-for="(image,index) in images>
    <a @click="zoomImgClicked(index)">
        <img :src="image.filename" :class={'max-w-full' : imgclicked[index]==1,'w-12' : imgclicked[index]==0}"> 
    </a> // using this.imgclicked[index] gives me the error 'this.imgclicked[0] is undefined'
</template>
```

on click the method *zoomImgClicked()* ist launched:

```
   zoomImgClicked: function(i){
        if(this.imgclicked[i]==0){
          this.imgclicked[i]=1
        }else{
          this.imgclicked[i]=0
        }
    },
```

But this is not working. If I open the vue console and change the values of *imgclicked[0]* manually   from 0 to 1 it works (images ae being resized). Also I see the method doing it's work, when logging in the console, the values are changed from 0 to 1 and vice versa. But it's not reflected on the page @click.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) in the Vue docs.

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

You should use the [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) method for this:

```
this.$set(this.imgclicked, i, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [array syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax):

```
<img
  :src="image.filename"
  :class="[
    {
      'max-w-full': imgclicked[index]==1,
      'w-12': imgclicked[index]==0
    },
    'static class if need'
  ]"
>
```